# coadjoint orbits and symmetry

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, symmetry, symplectic-geometry

Suppose we have some Lie group $G$, and we consider a co-adjoint orbit $\Omega$, which is a symplectic manifold. Does $G$ act on $\Omega$  by symplectomorphisms?  As in, is $G$ a symmetry of $\Omega$,  (an action that preserves symplectic structure)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the action is even Hamiltonian, with moment map given by the inclusion of $\Omega$ into $g^*$. You can check this directly.